# configuring the advanced forum module

Tags: drupal

Is there a way to control which pages to display the "New topic" and "Mark all as read" buttons while using the advanced forums module in drupal .

Answer (score 3):

Place advf-forums.tpl.php into your theme (take source from naked\advf-forums.tpl.php), after this your can control these buttons by modifying $links (read comments there).